# How to get the day from timezone in java

Tags: java, date, timezone

My Input will be timezone

```
String timeZone = currentTimeZone.getID();
timezone = America/Los_Angeles
```

Out put should be the day belongs to that timezone .

```
Monday
```

Here is what I have tried so far.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss"); 
Date datetime = new Date(); 
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta")); 
System.out.println("Asia/Calcutta "+ sdf.format(datetime));
```

Comment: Please show what have you tried so far and explain specific problem you are having.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            Date datetime = new Date();
            sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
            System.out.println("Asia/Calcutta "+ sdf.format(datetime));

Comment: Please add that to question

Comment: Please search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 1):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar LATime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
LATime.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
int year = LATime.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = LATime.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int date = LATime.get(Calendar.DATE);
int dayOfWeek = calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
```

Try it out

Comment: Only the day out of it  OUTPUT=MONDAY

Comment: dayOfWeek will give you day, you can omit others

Comment: it will return integer

Comment: DAY_OF_WEEK
public static final int DAY_OF_WEEK
Field number for get and set indicating the day of the week. This field takes values SUNDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, and SATURDAY.

Answer (score 0):

You can use other answer which gives you an integer and then you can map that to Day of Week accordingly or you can use `SimpleDateFormat` to print Day of Week like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
Date datetime = new Date();
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
System.out.println("America/Los_Angeles " + sdf.format(datetime));
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
>  String[] days =
>                 {"Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};
>         Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
>         Calendar LATime = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
>         LATime.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
>         int year = LATime.get(Calendar.YEAR);
>         int month = LATime.get(Calendar.MONTH);
>         int date = LATime.get(Calendar.DATE);
>         int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
>         System.out.println(days[dayOfWeek -1]);
```

Also we can set the calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(); default it is sunday the starting of the week.